# Count posts based on more than one meta key value

Tags: arrays, wordpress, loops, meta-key

I'm trying to count the number of posts where certain meta key values exist, in this case posts that have a key 'texture' with the value 'soft', and also have a key 'colours' that are 'red', 'blue' or 'green'.

My code does not error, but it appears to count **all** posts instead of just the ones with the meta key values as mentioned:

```
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page'    => -1,
    'post_type'         => 'post',
    'post_status'       => 'publish',
    'author'            => $current_user_id,
    'meta_query' => array(
       'key'   => 'texture',
       'value' => 'soft'
    ),
    array(
       'key'   => 'colours',
       'value' => array('red', 'blue', 'green')
    )
);

$posts_query = new WP_Query($args);
$the_count = $posts_query->post_count;

echo $the_count;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `'relationship' => 'AND'` in `meta_query` and `'compare' => 'IN'` in meta array that have multiple values *`('red', 'blue', 'green')`* like this :

```
'meta_query' => array(
    'relationship' => 'AND',
    array(
        'key'   => 'texture',
        'value' => 'soft'
    ),
    array(
        'key'   => 'colours',
        'value' => array('red', 'blue', 'green'),
        'compare' => 'IN'
    )
)
```

<kbd>**Edit #1:**</kbd>

Maybe adding `%` mark around your values would solve problem, I'm not 100% sure it would work but you can try it, like this:

```
'meta_query' => array(
    'relationship' => 'AND',
    array(
        'key'   => 'texture',
        'value' => 'soft'
    ),
    array(
        'key'   => 'colours',
        'value' => array('%red%', '%blue%', '%green%'),
        'compare' => 'IN'
    )
)
```

*I hope it works, Thanks..*

Comment: I would have expected that to work, but it still counts all posts.

Comment: Yes I had - unless you've updated it again since the update?

Comment: Never-mind i will rollback edits, wordPress automatically wraps the wildcard character ( % ) around the meta_value string, but i suggest adding % manually just for test..

Comment: Thanks, same result. This is very odd.